# redirect to html from cgi once the page is fully written

Tags: javascript, html, perl, dwr

I have searched for a case similar to mine and found few related posts but none of them could answer my question.

The cgi script I'm executing is crunching some numbers and at the end is spiting out a html file. I am controlling the location of this html file and providing a url to it on a transient website that is displayed upon successful submission of the html form.

The output html is created within a moment, or it is not created instantly in other words.

Is there a way to check within my temporary cgi page, whether the html has been fully written and then redirect to it automatically? If the page isn't ready I would like user to stay on the current page.

At the moment on my temporary cgi page I display 'check' and 'terminate' buttons where you can check for the status/terminate it. When 'check' is clicked and the website is ready then I redirect to it.
Also I display a url to the html file which you can go to but will be presented with just a fragment of the page if followed immediately.

I would like the refresh/redirect to be automatic so user doesn't have to click on anything.

I've seen elsewhere an idea to 'try to load a known small image and you detect if the loading is done or not':

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
  onload="window.location='http://www.example.com';"
  onerror="window.location='#';">
```

I like that, but it's not perfect. My temporary cgi page won't pass further the url to the results html without submitting a form (no GET, no POST here, since no form is used). Once again I would like the redirecting to be as automatic as possible.

So to summarize: how can I check from within a page generated with the CGI.pm whether outside html page is ready to be redirected to?
Is the DWR (http://directwebremoting.org) the only solution?

I would be happy to accept some JavaScript solutions.

**EDIT:**

I start writing to the result page right after the initial form is submitted and keep adding to it on the fly.
It is rather not easy/possible to check for the non-404 response (and then redirect) as already suggested since the page exists from the beginning (but is not complete).

Answer (score 4):

Since you control writing of result HTML, I presume both page generated from CGI and static results are on same domain. Set up on "waiting" page a function called periodically with `.setInterval` that would try to request result page with AJAX and, as soon as you receive non-404 response, set `window.location` to result page. Also provide some visual indicator / distraction to user, so they won't think they stuck.

When you generating your result page, you should first save it with some temporary file name and then rename it to final name when done, so it won't appear at intended address before it is complete.

Comment: Using a js framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) would make that a very simple task.

Comment: I imagine it is. I'm not that fluent in JavaScript though. I will give it a try unless you have some simple skeleton that I could expand on.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov Please see me edit. How would you approach this now?